# Swing Worker Thread Says There is no Process() Method In Super Class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I am trying to implement the SwingWorker Thread in updating my GUI. I understand that the process() method is executed by the EDT, so if i need to update the GUI, I should place the update code within that method.

However, when i try to override the process() method, I get the error, Method does not implement a method from the supertype.

Please am I Missing something or the Process() method no longer exist?

```
class SwingWorkerThread extends SwingWorker<String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        String Pub = "A";

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Pub = String.valueOf(i);

            publish(Pub);
        }

        return Pub;
    }

    @Override
    protected String process(String h) {
        System.out.println(Pub);
        MainFrame.TextArea.setText(Pub);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        String status;
        status = get();
        try {

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: unless thats an inner class .... this will not compile. Are you even using a proper IDE or do you simply hack something into some command console?

Answer (score 3):

There is no `String process(String)` method on `SwingWorker`. There is a `void process(List<V>)`, which is probably what you want.

(That still won't fix the fact that `Pub` is a local variable and not visible in that method.)

Answer (score 2):

[`SwingWorker`'s `process`method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#process-java.util.List-) has different arguments and a different return type:

```
protected void process(List<V> chunks)
```

Only methods of a subclass with the same signature (that is: name plus number and type of its parameters) and return type can override superclass methods, cf. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html.

Comment: I have been able to fix it.

Comment: However, my GUI hooks while the doInBackgound is still working. I thought Updating my GUI from the process() method will sove this, but its not. Please, how do I go about this